# Выводит ошибочное масимальное

Tags: c++, c

Почему выводит ошибочное максимальное (не входящее в массив d[26] = {0})?

```
while ((w = getchar()) != EOF) {
  if (w >= 'a' || w <= 'z')
    d[w-'a']++;
  if (max < d[w-'a'])
    max = d[w-'a'];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Второе условие надо спрятать под первое, иначе при вводе чего-нибудь, не являющегося строчной буквой, вы залезаете за пределы массива:

```
while((w = getchar()) != EOF){
  if(w >= 'a' || w <= 'z') {
    d[w-'a']++;
    if(max < d[w-'a']) max = d[w-'a'];
  }
}
```

Плюс убедитесь, что вы не забыли инициализировать `max` нулем.